# What went wrong? Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r

```r
> # Check results
> model_knn$results
  k  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD
1 5 0.9632391 0.9439746 0.02452539 0.03727995
2 7 0.9699800 0.9544974 0.02451292 0.03708112
3 9 0.9677304 0.9509734 0.02617121 0.03986928
> # Predict the labels of the test set
> predictions<-predict.train(object=model_knn,iris_norm.test[,1:4], type="raw")
> 
> # Evaluate the predictions
> table(predictions)
predictions
    Iris-setosa Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica 
             12              14              10 
> 
> #confusion matrix
> 
> # ENTER YOUR CODE HERE
> confusionMatrix(predictions,iris_norm.test[,5])
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Comment: the `data` and `reference` arguments to `confusionMatrix` should be factors with the same levels, as the error says. This is apparently not the case with `predictions` and `iris_norm.test[,5]`.

Comment: Hey Missy, welcome to SO! It would help if you can share just a little more detail about how you arrived at `model_knn`, what packes you used and where your `iris_norm.test` is from. That all helps to make the above code snipped [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Moreover, if you can share the output of `str(predictions)` and `str(iris_norm.test)` or more specifically, `levels(predictions)` and `levels(iris_norm.test[,5])`, you'll get more helpful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Without the model or data to reproduce your case, I can only suggest to align the factor levels using `forcats::fct_unify` before passing the two vectors into `confusionMatrix`:

```
library(forcats)
library(caret)

do.call(
  confusionMatrix,
  fct_unify(list(
    data = predictions,
    reference = iris_norm.test[,5]
  ))
)
```

`fct_unify` works on a list of factor vectors and makes sure they all share the same set of levels. Constructing that list with names corresponding to the expected arguments of `confusionMatrix`, I can pass it right into  with `do.call`.